# Postman: mock server input parameters

Tags: postman

I have created a mock server. I access it via {{url}}/mock1 and the response body I have mocked is the below.

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "LETTER": "A"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "LETTER": "B"
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "LETTER": "C"
    }
]
```

How can I simulate passing some input parameters in the GET request? For example, if I just want to retrieve the ID 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass input parameters as query parameters in the GET request.

The request URL would look like this: `{{url}}/mock1?ID=1`

In your mock server code, you can retrieve the value of the ID parameter and use it to filter the response data to only include the matching ID.

Here's an example in JavaScript using Express:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const mockData = [
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "LETTER": "A"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "LETTER": "B"
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "LETTER": "C"
    }
];

app.get('/mock1', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.query.ID;
    let responseData = mockData;
    if (id) {
        responseData = mockData.filter(data => data.ID == id);
    }
    res.send(responseData);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Mock server listening on port 3000');
});
```

This code sets up a mock server using Express and listens on port 3000. The GET request handler retrieves the value of the ID query parameter and uses it to filter the mock data. If the ID parameter is not present, the full mock data is returned.

---

**Edit 1:**

To create a mock server in Postman, follow these steps:

1 Open Postman and click on the "Mock Server" button in the header.

2 Click on the "Create a mock server" button.

3 Select the collection you want to associate with the mock server. If you don't have any collections, create a new one.

4 Choose a unique name for your mock server and a description (optional).

5 Define the endpoint and the response you want to return for the endpoint. To simulate the code you posted, create an endpoint with the path "/mock1" and a GET method. In the response section, set the status code to 200 and the response body to the mock data:

```
[
{
"ID": 1,
"LETTER": "A"
},
{
"ID": 2,
"LETTER": "B"
},
{
"ID": 3,
"LETTER": "C"
}
]
```

6 If you want to simulate filtering by "ID", you can use the "Tests" tab to write a script that retrieves the "ID" query parameter and returns the filtered data.

7 Save your changes and publish the mock server. You'll be provided with a URL that you can use to make requests to your mock server.

Note: This will create a mock server within Postman and does not require you to write any code or have a server running on your machine.

Comment: I have just tried in postman but there is no way of configuring the mock server to add this kind of code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check if the edited part of the answer helps.

Comment: Ok, but if I understand correctly step 6, there is no way of making the Mock Server accept  an input and return based on that but it must be filtered by the requester after the Mock Server has return the whole thing?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The mock server in Postman will return a pre-defined response, and there is no built-in functionality to filter the response based on query parameters in the same way as in the code example I provided using Express. However, you can write scripts using the Tests tab in Postman to process the response from the mock server and return a filtered result to the requester. This will require the requester to have the appropriate processing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

On client side in URL you should send the `query string` (name/value pairs) in the URL of a GET request:

```
{{url}}/mock1?ID=1
```

On server side you should receive and handle this `ID` parameter.

For more details check [HTTP Request Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: But postman is returning the whole response, not filtering it by the input parameters.

Comment: It seems, that you don't receive and handle this GET parameter on server side. 
You need update your mock service to return only entity with matching ID.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to do that? Even the simplest example would do.

Comment: What language do you use for your mock service?

Comment: Below few examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-can-i-get-parameters-from-a-url-string
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-get-url-parameters.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/get-the-values-from-the-get-parameters-javascript

Comment: My question is more how to do it in postman, not sure if the answer would be that there is no option to do that there.